# How to read data from numpy files in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

How can I read data from numpy.ndarray files using queues and readers?

Can I just use [tf.WholeFileReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#WholeFileReader) to read the file followed by a [tf.decode_raw](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_raw) to convert it to the appropriate type?